# SQL query for date formats

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me in writing a  query for creating a table which will store date in the format of `month/date/year` (`mm/dd/_ _ _ _`)?

I do not want to use `varchar`, because I will be needing to compare my dates also. I also do not want to use any other date formats because my inputs are being entered in the format of `month/date/year` (`mm/dd/_ _ _ _`)?

Comment: Use the native date type in whatever database you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Dates don't have a "format"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `varchar` and it can be converted using the option `101` to the format you want (`mm/dd/yyyy`).

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, '2017/10/02', 111), 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to depend on what type of database you are using (SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSql, etc.) and whether you are doing this with 100% SQL, or if you have an application that uses another language that could manipulate the data as well.

Assuming this is an all SQL application, if you need to compare the dates, you will likely need to use the native Date data type for whatever database you are using.

By contrast, you could store it as a varchar, but then would need to cast it as a date for comparison.

To get the date into the format the you are needing, again depending on the database, you may have some sort of date_format function available to input/output the date in the format that you need. If there is not a native function for your database, someone has likely come up with a solution for that database. Searching for your database type (MySQL, Postgresql, etc.) and "date format" will be a good starting point.

If your application is also using another language, it may also have some native functions to convert the date into the format that you need.

I know this didn't directly answer your question, but hopefully gets you thinking about different ways to solve the problem and gets you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use varchar and then convert it to your desired format. Here is a sample query.

```
DECLARE @s DATETIME

SELECT @s = CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/13/2013', 101)
```

Comment: To know more about converting data, you can have a look in the following link.https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: And this one for all the available formats. http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx